# Create symmetrical list from existing list

Tags: python

I have list of ints that looks like this:

```
a = [-10, -100, -1000, -2000, -3000]
```

I would like to create a new list from this list:

```
b = [-10, -100, -1000, -2000, -3000, -3000, -2000, -1000, -100, -10]
```

I know this is possible doing something like:

```
b = a[::-1]
res = a + b
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing it though?

Comment: how more efficient can you get? You could compress it to one line with `res = a + a[::-1]`, but that's it

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering if there some cool way to do it with a function from a package or something @Mahrkeenerh

Comment: @Dila For this simple task, there is no need. Another option might be using unpacking: `[*a, *reversed(a)]`. But I am sceptical about whether that has a significant advantage (if any).

Comment: calling a function will likely make is slower since function calls have overhead

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the temporary variable `b` so that there's no extra copy of `a[::-1]` hanging around.

```
res = a + a[::-1]
```

Comment: This does not prevent a copy being made

Comment: @juanpa What do you mean? I know a copy needs to be *made* in order to construct `res`, but it'll be garbage collected instead of kept via `b`.

Comment: @juanpa I edited to try to clarify

Comment: This is "visually" more efficient, but you can always just use `del b` to clean up the temporary list as well.

Comment: @chepner I don't see any reason to create `b` in the first place

Answer (score 0):

So for this issue, the only 3 realistic solutions seem to be adding the reversed slice of `a`, copying `a` and extending it by the reversed slice, and unpacking `a` along with unpacking `reversed(a)`:

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = 'a = [-10, -100, -1000, -2000, -3000]'

print(timeit('a + a[::-1]', setup))
print(timeit('a.copy().extend(a[::-1])', setup))
print(timeit('[*a, *reversed(a)]', setup))
```

And my results are:

```
0.5961677939922083
0.8394856759987306
0.8519255819992395
```

So in conclusion the former is definitely the most efficient approach.

As for if you had an iterable and wanted to do this you would be forced to consume it as there is no way to reverse an iterable without doing so. For instance:

```
a = (i%2 for i in range(100))
b = list(a)
reversed = a + a[::-1]
```

Note for `range` you can take slices of it, so no need to use `list` on them:

```
print(*range(10)[::-1])
#9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: [faster](https://tio.run/##bY3LCgIhAEX3fsXdqaSQDUFM9Av9wDCEhFNCPlBb9PVmOcvZnMOFAzd@yjP44RRTrUsKDsU6YwusiyGVdRGSTXlHXEB1wyTVXqBh5U@HrqFpPiO3Kr/s3bBr8EagUypOCVlCwg3WI2n/MOzIR4KYrC@sn7H2sYOexlGqmQr8rznfjvJGwWv9Ag)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode how is that actually faster?

Comment: By not building a new slice object every time.

Comment: I did but I was looking for a clarification as to how. Just interesting that would be faster.

Comment: See the updated comment.

Comment: [And see this](https://tio.run/##NYvBCsMgEETvfsXeskJSCL0Ur7n3B0qQEDftglGJe2i@3tpKB2YYmDfplFcM11s6Sln9kjNMRkGVow2sfZKw0G4tZvJbDxwcvXUjvkoHB0E5E2Gb/oiaUD@MGcb517LnlfAeA/XQchj1rBTvKR4CjrOqvlRjt7Rfp0v5AA).